# Adding a dependency to a batch task at runtime

Tags: batch-processing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a batch job in AX 2012 R2 that runs, essentially iterating over a table and creating an instance of a class (that extends RunBaseBatch) that gets added as a task.

I also have some post processing items I need to do, after all the tasks have completed.

So far, the following is working:

```
while select stagingTable where stagingTable.OperationNo == params.paramOperationNo()
{
    batchHeader = this.getCurrentBatchHeader();
    batchTask = OperationTask::construct();
    batchHeader.addRuntimeTask(batchTask,this.getCurrentBatchTask().RecId);

}

batchHeader.save();
postTask = PostProcessingTask::construct();
batchHeader.addRuntimeTask(postTask,this.getCurrentBatchTask().RecId);
batchHeader.addDependency(postTask,batchTask,BatchDependencyStatus::FinishedOrError);
batchHeader.save();
```

My thought is that this will add a dependency on the post process task to not start until we get Finished or Error on the last task added in the loop.  What I get instead is an exception "The dependency could not be created because task '' does not exist."

I'm uncertain what I'm missing, as the tasks all get added executed successfully, it seems that just the dependency doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things, where this code is being called matters.  Is the code already in batch? Is the code calling in `doBatch()` before/after the super? etc.

You have a while-select, does this create multiple batch tasks?  If it does, then you need to create a dependency on **each** batch task object.  This is one problem I see.  If your while-select statement only selects 1 record and adds one task, then the problem is something else, but you shouldn't do a while-select to select one record.

Also, you call `batchHeader.save();` two times.  I'd probably remove the first call. I'd need to see what is instantiating your code.

Where you have `this.getCurrentBatchTask().RecId`, depending on if your code is in batch or not, try replacing that with `BatchHeader::getCurrentBatchTask().RecId`

And where you have `batchHeader = this.getCurrentBatchHeader();` replace that with `batchHeader = BatchHeader::getCurrentBatchHeader();`

> **EDIT** Try this code (fix whatever to make it compile)

```
BatchHeader     batchHeader = BatchHeader::getCurrentBatchHeader();
Set             set         = new Set(Types::Class);
SetEnumerator   se;
BatchTask       batchTask;
PostTask        postTask;

while select stagingTable where stagingTable.OperationNo == params.paramOperationNo()
{
    batchTask = OperationTask::construct();
    set.add(batchTask);
    batchHeader.addRuntimeTask(batchTask,BatchHeader::getCurrentBatchTask().RecId);
}

// Create post task
postTask = PostProcessingTask::construct();
batchHeader.addRuntimeTask(postTask,BatchHeader::getCurrentBatchTask().RecId);

// Create dependencies
se = set.getEnumerator();
while (se.moveNext())
{
    batchTask = se.current(); // Task to make dependent on    
    batchHeader.addDependency(postTask,batchTask,BatchDependencyStatus::FinishedOrError);
}

batchHeader.save();
```

Comment: Also, `batchTask` is constructed in the `while select` which means if there is no records in your staging table, you will get a null exception.

Comment: At this point in execution, I have already verified that the staging table contains data.  This bit of code is run in after we get an AIF service request.  The AIF service creates a task to run using the SysOperationFramework.  That task, in turn, performs what's going on above

Comment: What about the other comments in my post? Does the while loop select more than one record? Multiple calls to `.save()`, replacing with `BatchHeader::getCurrentBatch[...]`?

Comment: just tried this, moving the creation of the PostProcessing task into the first loop iteration (with a quick boolean) and then adding the dependency each time, and adding that dependency to each task (the loop can create 1 to many tasks, in this test case, it would be 11), same exception

Comment: Inside the loop, if you create 10 tasks, and each task, you create 1 post processing task dependent on that `batchTask`, you understand that means 1 `batchTask` and 1 `postTask` are created at the same time with each dependent on ONLY each other. So you will have 10 pairs of tasks that are 1-1 and 1-1 and 1-1 dependent on each other.  If you want ALL of the post tasks to start after ALL of the batchTasks have finished, you need to make every `post` task dependent on every `batch` task. Create a `Set set = new Set(Types::Class)`, and fill that with the created `batchTask`s, then loop the set

Comment: So after you are outside of the loop, loop over the `set` of `batchTask` classes that you built inside the loop, and create `postTask` batch dependencies.

Comment: I just edited my answer to put some sample code for you. You may need to modify it to fit your code, but the same basic structure should stay the same. The code will create X amount of `batchTask`s and then create 1 `postTask` and make it dependent on every one of those `batchTask`s

Comment: Excellent.  I'm able to get the post processing task added now with the proper dependencies.  Thanks for all of the help

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help. It's not terribly straight forward at first, but hopefully after seeing the code it makes sense.